# Nested Elsif condition handling in python-Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, nested

I was writing some nested if else using `np.where`
But not able to write a successful executable code for the below program.
I tried handling `Aim` and `Target` values separately. 
While doing so, it is expecting a `Target` value for second T1 condition before entering into further.

Is there a way to handle two values `Aim` and `Target` from the defined condition (like passing in a tuple or list or dictionary).

```
    If T1 < 10 Then
        Aim= 100
        Target = 200
    ElseIf T1 < 70 Then
        Aim= 25
        If T2 < 250 Then
            Target = 'A'
        ElseIf T2 < 500 Then
            Target = B
        Else
            Target = C
        End If
    ElseIf T1 > 100 Then
        Aim= 300
        If T2 < 250 Then
            Target = A
        Else
            Target = 'B'
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Hmm... that doesn't look like [Python if-else syntax](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else) to me.  Perhaps I'm wrong. Meanwhile, please take your time to familiarise yourself with the site by taking _[the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)_ and reading up on _[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_. Thanks!

Comment: I provided an example of spinet i am trying to work for. Would like to change using numpy or pandas.

Comment: can you post a sample dataframe and expected dataframe